# How to run knowrob without shell but using prolog language?

Tags: knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I want to load knowrob system to run prolog src to do the following thing:

```
  owl_parser:owl_parse('/home/sam/code/ros/ai/owl/sam_world.owl', false, false, true).
```

How to run knowrob just loading pl file without login to a shell?

Thank you~

---

I follow @Lorenz answer.

I create ros package: sam_knowrob_test

my init.pl

```
  register_ros_package(mod_vis).
  register_ros_package(ias_semantic_map).
  visualisation_canvas(C).
```

I run rosrun command,but it couldn't show Semantic map:

```
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/ai$ rosrun rosprolog rosprolog sam_knowrob_test
  % library(swi_hooks) compiled into pce_swi_hooks 0.00 sec, 3,616 bytes
  %     library(error) compiled into error 0.00 sec, 17,688 bytes
  %    library(lists) compiled into lists 0.01 sec, 41,424 bytes
  %   library(shlib) compiled into shlib 0.01 sec, 62,200 bytes
  %   library(option) compiled into swi_option 0.00 sec, 15,080 bytes
  %  library(process) compiled into process 0.01 sec, 93,400 bytes
  % /opt/ros/electric/stacks/knowrob/rosprolog/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.01 sec, 100,848 bytes
  Warning: /home/sam/code/ros/ai/knowrob/sam_knowrob_test/prolog/init.pl:1:
    Redefined static procedure register_ros_package/1
  Warning: /home/sam/code/ros/ai/knowrob/sam_knowrob_test/prolog/init.pl:3:
    Singleton variables: [C]
  % /home/sam/code/ros/ai/knowrob/sam_knowrob_test/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 960 bytes
  ?-
```

It also show warning:

```
 Singleton variables: [C]
```

I try to run by input but nothing happened:

```
  ?- register_ros_package(mod_vis).
  true .
  
  ?- register_ros_package(ias_semantic_map).
  true.
  
  ?- visualisation_canvas(C).
  true.
  
  ?-
```

Why it couldn't show semantic map?

How to fixed it?

Thank you~

---

```
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/ai$ rosrun rosprolog rosprolog sam_knowrob_test
  % library(swi_hooks) compiled into pce_swi_hooks 0.00 sec, 3,616 bytes
  %     library(error) compiled into error 0.00 sec, 17,688 bytes
  %    library(lists) compiled into lists 0.00 sec, 41,424 bytes
  %   library(shlib) compiled into shlib 0.00 sec, 62,200 bytes
  %   library(option) compiled into swi_option 0.01 sec, 15,080 bytes
  %  library(process) compiled into process 0.01 sec, 93,400 bytes
  % /opt/ros/electric/stacks/knowrob/rosprolog/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.01 sec, 100,848 bytes
  %     library(jpl) compiled into jpl 0.02 sec, 285,496 bytes
  %         library(sgml) compiled into sgml 0.01 sec, 38,464 bytes
  %           library(quintus) compiled into quintus 0.00 sec, 21,384 bytes
  %          rewrite compiled into rewrite 0.00 sec, 34,736 bytes
  %          library(uri) compiled into uri 0.00 sec, 10,880 bytes
  %          library(record) compiled into record 0.00 sec, 31,072 bytes
  %         rdf_parser compiled into rdf_parser 0.01 sec, 145,344 bytes
  %          library(gensym) compiled into gensym 0.00 sec, 4,432 bytes
  %         rdf_triple compiled into rdf_triple 0.00 sec, 37,168 bytes
  %        library(rdf) compiled into rdf 0.02 sec, 271,184 bytes
  %         library(debug) compiled into prolog_debug 0.00 sec, 21,320 bytes
  %         library(assoc) compiled into assoc 0.00 sec, 22,640 bytes
  %        library(sgml_write) compiled into sgml_write 0.01 sec, 105,192 bytes
  %        library(nb_set) compiled into nb_set 0.00 sec, 5,968 bytes
  %         library(utf8) compiled into utf8 0.00 sec, 14,112 bytes
  %        library(url) compiled into url 0.00 sec, 113,536 bytes
  %        rdf_cache compiled into rdf_cache 0.00 sec, 15,904 bytes
  %       library(semweb/rdf_db) compiled into rdf_db 0.04 sec, 680,768 bytes
  %      comp_similarity compiled into comp_similarity 0.04 sec, 708,256 bytes
  %     /opt/ros/electric/stacks/knowrob/ias_prolog_addons/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.04 sec, 709,136 bytes
  %      library(broadcast) compiled into broadcast 0.00 sec, 7,344 bytes
  %     library(semweb/rdf_edit) compiled into rdf_edit 0.01 sec, 86,712 bytes
  %     library(semweb/rdfs) compiled into rdfs 0.00 sec, 25,992 bytes
  %     library(semweb/owl) compiled into t20_owl 0.01 sec, 68,496 bytes
  %       library(socket) compiled into socket 0.00 sec, 10,232 bytes
  %       library(base64) compiled into base64 0.00 sec, 17,400 bytes
  %      library(http/http_open.pl) compiled into http_open 0.00 sec, 77,056 bytes
  %     library(thea/owl_parser) compiled into owl_parser 0.01 sec, 155,976 bytes
  %      library(odbc) compiled into odbc 0.00 sec, 37,344 bytes
  %     library(semweb/rdfs_computable) compiled into rdfs_computable 0.00 sec, 87,488 bytes
  %    /opt/ros/electric/stacks/knowrob/semweb/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.09 sec, 1,463,728 bytes
  %        library(tf_prolog) compiled into tf_prolog 0.00 sec, 19,296 bytes
  %       /opt/ros/electric/stacks/knowrob/tf_prolog/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 20,424 bytes
  %        library(knowrob_owl) compiled into knowrob_owl 0.00 sec, 13,512 bytes
  %        library(knowrob_perception) compiled into knowrob_perception 0.01 sec, 22,128 bytes
  %       library(knowrob_objects) compiled into knowrob_objects 0.01 sec, 79,728 bytes
  %       library(knowrob_coordinates) compiled into knowrob_coordinates 0.00 sec, 18,048 bytes
  %      /opt/ros/electric/stacks/knowrob/knowrob_objects/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.01 sec, 128,752 bytes
  %      library(knowrob_actions) compiled into knowrob_actions 0.00 sec, 12,600 bytes
  %     /opt/ros/electric/stacks/knowrob/knowrob_actions/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.01 sec, 151,400 bytes
  %      library(util) compiled into util 0.01 sec, 27,328 bytes
  %     library(classifiers) compiled into classifiers 0.01 sec, 47,880 bytes
  %     library(jython) compiled into jython 0.00 sec, 24,256 bytes
  % Parsed "owl.owl" in 0.00 sec; 169 triples
  % Parsed "rdf-schema.xml" in 0.00 sec; 87 triples
  % Parsed "knowrob.owl" in 0.07 sec; 3,721 triples
  %    /opt/ros/electric/stacks/knowrob/ias_knowledge_base/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.63 sec, 1,988,552 bytes
  %    library(owl_export) compiled into owl_export 0.00 sec, 22,520 bytes
  %   /opt/ros/electric/stacks/knowrob/knowrob_common/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.73 sec, 3,490,280 bytes
  %   library(mod_vis) compiled into mod_vis 0.00 sec, 44,184 bytes
  %  /opt/ros/electric/stacks/knowrob/mod_vis/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.73 sec, 3,543,048 bytes
  % Parsed "comp_temporal.owl" in 0.01 sec; 164 triples
  %     library(comp_temporal) compiled into comp_temporal 0.59 sec, 328,520 bytes
  %    /opt/ros/electric/stacks/knowrob/comp_temporal/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.75 sec, 479,384 bytes
  % Parsed "comp_spatial.owl" in 0.01 sec; 459 triples
  %    library(comp_spatial) compiled into comp_spatial 0.21 sec, 371,056 bytes
  %   /opt/ros/electric/stacks/knowrob/comp_spatial/prolog/init.pl compiled 1.13 sec, 1,008,568 bytes
  %    library(semweb/actionmodel) compiled into actionmodel 0.01 sec, 106,696 bytes
  % Parsed "ccrl2_semantic_map.owl" in 0.03 sec; 2,226 triples
  %   ccrl2_semantic_map compiled 0.58 sec, 1,042,856 bytes
  %   semantic_map_utils compiled into ias_semantic_map 0.00 sec, 15,136 bytes
  %  /opt/ros/electric/stacks/knowrob/ias_semantic_map/prolog/init.pl compiled 1.72 sec, 2,077,408 bytes
  Warning: /home/sam/code/ros/ai/knowrob/sam_knowrob_test/prolog/init.pl:3:
    Singleton variables: [C]
  ControlP5 0.5.4 infos, comments, questions at http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5
  PeasyCam v105
  2012/8/8 下午 11:35:47 controlP5.ControlWindow init
  資訊: You are using renderer processing.core.PGraphics3D.
  In order to render controlP5 elements you need to call the ControlP5's draw() manually.
  Suggestion is to put controlP5.draw(); at the bottom of the draw function of your sketch.
  ERROR: /home/sam/code/ros/ai/knowrob/sam_knowrob_test/prolog/init.pl:3:
    Java exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jpl in java.library.path
  Warning: /home/sam/code/ros/ai/knowrob/sam_knowrob_test/prolog/init.pl:3:
    Goal (directive) failed: user:visualisation_canvas(_G209)
  % /home/sam/code/ros/ai/knowrob/sam_knowrob_test/prolog/init.pl compiled 3.88 sec, 6,740,064 bytes
  ?-
```

How to fix this error?

```
  ERROR: /home/sam/code/ros/ai/knowrob/sam_knowrob_test/prolog/init.pl:3:
    Java exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jpl in java.library.path
```

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40752/how-to-run-knowrob-without-shell-but-using-prolog-language?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-08-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Create a new ROS package that depends on rosprolog, create a sub-directory named prolog and create a file init.pl with your prolog code in that sub-directory.

Now you can run it with

```
rosrun rosprolog rosprolog <your package>
```

This will cause the file init.pl to be executed. If your prolog code ever happens to terminates at some point, a prolog shell will still appear. However I wouldn't consider that a problem. That's just how prolog works.

**Edit**: Your prolog code doesn't look quite correct, you are getting warnings when loading it. If you want to evaluate predicates, you need to use `:-` at the beginning of an expression. Otherwise you try to re-define predicates. Your init.pl file should look like this:

```
:- register_ros_package(mod_vis).
:- register_ros_package(ias_semantic_map).
:- visualisation_canvas(_).
```

You can always test it by executing the following in your prolog shell:

```
?- consult('/path/to/init.pl').
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-08-08**:
I edit my original post. Why I couldn't show semantic map by init.pl? Thank you~

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-08-08**:
I edit init.pl and my original post. Now I can show controlP5window, but failed to show semantic map. It has jpl error. How to fix it? Thank you~

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-08**:
What are your package's dependencies in manifest.xml? You need to depend on jpl, mod_vis and ias_semantic_map.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In addition to Lorenz' answer: You normally want to have some kind of shell, because otherwise the information from the OWL file lives happily in KnowRob, but nobody can ask for it. If you don't want to have an interactive shell, but want to query KnowRob from other ROS nodes, have a look at the examples in the json_prolog package. json_prolog starts a service that offers a Prolog query interface to other ROS components, but does not offer an interactive shell to the user.

Moritz

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2012-08-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-08-08**:
For non-interactive shell, what's difference between using json_prolog and rosprolog with init.pl ?

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2012-08-08**:
json_prolog offers a ROS service, rosprolog offers a shell to the user. Both do not offer the other thing.